# How to check if Regex matches before some index without searching entire string, or if regex matches at an index in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have a case where I'm using regex to check a string for matches, after a start index and before an end one.

To set the start point, it is possible to create a `new Regexp()` and set it's index before running `exec()`.

I can not find a way, though, to limit the depth of its search.  One "obvious" solution might be to use `substring()` to get a string that can't be searched passed a point, but it would have a massive negative impact on performance.  Any solution to setting a limit on regex search depth that includes `substring()` will not do, and is IMO embarrassingly inefficient, so please do not post them.

The three ways I can imagine fixing this are:

1. if there is some way to set a limit, such as `myRegex.exec(string, stopIndex)` or `myString.length = temporaryFakeLimit; //do regex, reset length`.  Neither of these work or exist.
2. if there was some way to check for a regex match at an index in a string ie `myRegex.testAt(myString, indexToCheck)`, I could iterate through the string myself, checking for matches.
3. if there was a non-native implementation of regex, which is capable of doing either of the above.

So far I have not been able to find a good solution.

**How can I check if a Regex has a match in a string before some index, without it searching the entire string?**

---

### Edit (Not by OP)

#### To add further:

> If it doesn't find a match, and I'm only looking 100 chars deep on a 100000 char text, that's an issue.

**How can we search a portion of a given string using RegEx. This portion of string should be determined by parameters indicating a start index and an end index.**

### Example of Parameters

```
var str = `Check enhancement bonus fear effect fly initiative check panicked points of damage rounding stunned touch attack unarmed strike. Aquatic subtype attack of opportunity catching on fire charm conjuration deafened evasion evil domain fast healing favored class fire domain gaseous form healing subschool incorporeal melee weapon multiplying skill points stunned summoning subschool take 10 turn. Adjacent class concentrate on a spell energy drained infection intelligence invisible law domain mundane nonlethal damage small.`;

var rgx = /\d\d/;

var start = 300;

var end = 500;
```

The result should be:

> 10

Comment: What is the input string and expected result?

Comment: There is no input string or expected result.  This is not that kind of RegExp question.  If you must have one, the string is `"test string"`, the limit of depth is 4, and the regex is `/i/`.  It should return no match, because "string" is after index 4.

Comment: _"There is no input string or expected result. This is not that kind of RegExp question."_ ? Not sure what you mean? An input string is necessary to match a portion of the string, else no problem statement exists at the Question relevant to `RegExp`.

Comment: This is a question about a function of RegExp that doesn't appear to exist.  There is no way to create code using a function that doesn't exist.

Comment: What do mean mean by "the limit of depth"? Do you mean match `"test"` only is `"test"` if after index `4` within `"test string"`?

Comment: The index in the string at which searching should stop.  A limit, or range, for cases where the entire string need not be searched.

Comment: Just check the `RegExp.lastIndex` value after each match and if it is bigger than your limit, stop.

Comment: One approach would be to use a loop and `break`

Comment: @SephReed You can use the `RegExp` within the `for` loop and specify the range of indexes which should be iterated, or simply utilize `===` operator and omit use of `RegExp` altogether.  Not certain why you are attempting to complicate the procedure?

Comment: The purpose of `RegExp` is to match or not match strings. What is the definition of `RegExp` that you are using at the present Question?

Comment: @SephReed Sorry for not explaining the downvote, but I kept on making a list of criticisms and I don't think it would be that productive. So in short, the questioner should be considerate and update the question to reflect one's comments. Comments are ephemeral this not a chat room. Btw your answer is overcomplicated see my new answer. It can actually go through 100,000 characters very well because this is the 21st century and browsers are much more powerful than they were back in the 90s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: ignore the following, the true answer to this question is that substr does not work in js the way I thought it did.  In native browser code, strings are immutable, so when substr() is called, it can just reference the original string with a new start and length property.  It's super efficient.

---

OLD ANSWER:

I've managed to figure out a solution for this, although it's ugly.  The idea is to use a regex that matches the thing you are looking for, or anything.  Because it will match anything if it doesn't match what you want, it moves one char at a time.  Using capturing groups, you can check if it's matching the thing you want, or the dummy matches.

The code for it is like so:

```js
var stringToSearch = "hey hi ho here we go, woop de do an2 for you, lalala lelele lolol goop da woop ba bee";

var whatIWant = "a.+[1-3]";
var anyChar = ".|\n"

var myRegex = new RegExp("("+whatIWant+")|"+anyChar, 'g');


function boundedRegexSearch(searchMe, regex, start, end) {
  regex.lastIndex = start; //start search index
  
  var keepSearching = true;
  while(keepSearching) {
    var result = regex.exec(searchMe);
    var whatImSearchingFor = result[1];
  
    if(whatImSearchingFor !== undefined)
      return whatImSearchingFor;
   
    keepSearching = regex.lastIndex < end;
  }
}


//can not match anything from index 0 to 8, returns undefined
console.log(boundedRegexSearch(stringToSearch, myRegex, 0, 8));

//can match "an2" at index 36
console.log(boundedRegexSearch(stringToSearch, myRegex, 20, 40));
```

Comment: Why did you take the time to edit your Answer, but not edit the original Question to provide greater clarity as to what the requirement is; for the Answer to match the Question 1:1?

Comment: Never use `(.|\n)` to match any char in a JS regex. Either use `[^]` or `[\s\S]` (if you need to port it later to other NFA regex engines)

Comment: In my new answer, [my simple function is 81% faster than boundedRegexSearch() when searching a string of over 100,000 character.](https://jsperf.com/so47086482) boundedRegexSearch() fails on many levels, but it should be obvious that using .|\n to drive incrementing a search is unnecessary and the g flag shouldn't even be used if you want to stop after the first search. There's no point in crawling over each char. the methods provided to the String and Regex Objects have optimal algorithms baked right in. And yes, even `substring()` can be used in a far better way and be faster and efficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand correctly your requirements but I think you can use something like this `(^.{0,4})(the actual regex)(.*)` and adjust the length by changing `4` with `[max size] - [actual regex length]`.

I don't know how exactly the regex engine is implemented in JavaScript but I think that by using something like this the engine won't process the entire string.

The example above will start the search at the start of the string. For starting at an offset, you can use something like this:

`(^.{5}.{0,4})(the actual regex)(.*)` where `5` is the offset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `for` loop and `break`

```js
let str = "test string";

let match = "string";

let limit = 4;

let res = "";

for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, i < limit);
  if (i >= limit - 1) {
    if (!res) {
      res = null;
    }
    break;
  };
  // alternatively, using `RegExp`
  // new RegExp(str[i], "i").test(match[i])
  if (str[i] === match[i]) { 
    res += str[i]
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

## OP Question

> How can I check if a Regex has a match in a string before some index, without it searching the entire string?

### Comment added to question

> If it doesn't find a match, and I'm only looking 100 chars deep on a 100000 char text, that's an issue. And this isn't about an expected output, it's about a function that doesn't seem to exist.

Taking both of these requirements from a badly managed question into consideration, we should do the following:

- Take 4 parameters: the string `str`, the RegEx `tgt`, the start index `ptA`, and the end index `ptZ`
- Extract a new string by using `slice(ptA, (ptZ+1))`. The `ptZ+1` is because `ptZ` is exclusive.
- Then use `match()` on the new string using `tgt`.

Since the OP emphasized performance, here's a test between OP answer and this answer at **[jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/so47086482)**.

### Demo

```js
const str = `Anything suspicious? Well... then should we go? Any uh... Cartel news these days? Seems like I'm always reading something or other in the paper. I don't want to talk about it. To you or anyone else. I'm done explaining myself. Gus is dead. We've got work to do. `;

let tgt = /Cartel/;

function searchIndexRange(str, rgx, ptA, ptZ) {
  const frag = str.slice(ptA, (ptZ + 1));
  let exists = frag.match(rgx);
  if (exists !== -1) {
    return exists;
  } else return false;
}

// First call returns null 
// Second call returns the search key "Cartel"

let res = JSON.stringify(searchIndexRange(str, tgt, 0, 1));
console.log(res);

res = JSON.stringify(searchIndexRange(str, tgt, 0, 100));
console.log(res);
```

Comment: I can't afford to pontificate, my job is purely based on results and performance, much like how SO is in a way. If it's broken fix it. Perhaps https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is more suited for you?

Comment: Like I said, results and performance is what I get paid for, edge cases such as `abababba` are not a real concern. Calling recursive calls on a string for C++ you can try `regex_match` function and use pointers to each match or something like that I haven't used C++ for years.